# How to consume a H2OModel computed and saved in Python API

Tags: java, python, h2o

I've been reading the H2O documentation for a while, and I haven't found a clear example of how to load `model` trained and saved using the Python API. I was following the next example.

```py
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.naive_bayes import H2ONaiveBayesEstimator

model = H2ONaiveBayesEstimator()
h2o_df = h2o.import_file("http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/airlines/allyears2k_headers.zip")
model.train(y = "IsDepDelayed", x = ["Year", "Origin"], 
            training_frame = h2o_df, 
            family = "binomial", 
            lambda_search = True, 
            max_active_predictors = 10)
h2o.save_model(model, path=models)
```

But if you check the official [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/index.html) it states that you have to download the model as a `POJO` from the flow UI. **Is it the only way?** or, **may I achieve the same result via python?** Just for information, I show the doc's example below. I need some guidance.

```java
import java.io.*;
import hex.genmodel.easy.RowData;
import hex.genmodel.easy.EasyPredictModelWrapper;
import hex.genmodel.easy.prediction.*;

public class main {
  private static String modelClassName = "gbm_pojo_test";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    hex.genmodel.GenModel rawModel;
    rawModel = (hex.genmodel.GenModel) Class.forName(modelClassName).newInstance();
    EasyPredictModelWrapper model = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(rawModel);
    //
    // By default, unknown categorical levels throw PredictUnknownCategoricalLevelException.
    // Optionally configure the wrapper to treat unknown categorical levels as N/A instead:
    //
    //     EasyPredictModelWrapper model = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(
    //                                         new EasyPredictModelWrapper.Config()
    //                                             .setModel(rawModel)
    //                                             .setConvertUnknownCategoricalLevelsToNa(true));

    RowData row = new RowData();
     row.put("Year", "1987");
     row.put("Month", "10");
     row.put("DayofMonth", "14");
     row.put("DayOfWeek", "3");
     row.put("CRSDepTime", "730");
     row.put("UniqueCarrier", "PS");
     row.put("Origin", "SAN");
     row.put("Dest", "SFO");

    BinomialModelPrediction p = model.predictBinomial(row);
    System.out.println("Label (aka prediction) is flight departure delayed: " + p.label);
    System.out.print("Class probabilities: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < p.classProbabilities.length; i++) {
      if (i > 0) {
        System.out.print(",");
      }
      System.out.print(p.classProbabilities[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `h2o.savemodel` and `h2o.loadmodel`?

Comment: `h2o.savemodel` http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-tibshirani/8/docs-website/h2o-py/docs/h2o.html?highlight=save_model#h2o.h2o.save_model

Comment: `h2o.loadmodel` http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-tibshirani/8/docs-website/h2o-py/docs/h2o.html?highlight=save_model#h2o.h2o.load_model

Comment: @jmuhlenkamp But I wanted to load those models using the Java's API.

Comment: how about `h2o.download_pojo` http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-tibshirani/8/docs-website/h2o-py/docs/h2o.html?highlight=save_model#h2o.h2o.download_pojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

h2o.save_model will save the binary model to the provided file system, however, looking at the Java application above it seems you want to use model into a Java based scoring application.

Because of that you should be using h2o.download_pojo API to save the model to local file system along with genmodel jar file. The API is documented as below:

```
download_pojo(model, path=u'', get_jar=True)
Download the POJO for this model to the directory specified by the path; if the path is "", then dump to screen.

:param model: the model whose scoring POJO should be retrieved.
:param path: an absolute path to the directory where POJO should be saved.
:param get_jar: retrieve the h2o-genmodel.jar also.
```

Once you have download POJO, you can use the above sample application to perform the scoring and make sure the POJO class name and the "modelClassName" are same along with model type.